# top.location.href doesn't work @ Opera

Tags: javascript, opera

i am using this little navigate code snippet

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(document.location.href.indexOf('.99')>-1)
{
  top.location.href = "http://bit.ly/xxx";
}
else
{
  top.location.href = "http://bit.ly/yyyy";
}
</script>
```

i have 2 ip on my server if its .98 i want to navigate to xxx if not to yyyy

just simple as that works at all browsers than opera

at opera only the else { } section works.

if you want see the demo

just go to that link : http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=qEyzcG3W

Comment: Try **window.location.href** instead.

Comment: @ Neal I use opera doesn't it count?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Use a serverside redirect.

Comment: What part exactly does not work? Also, your pastebin demo does not work, it is just an IP string

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
top.location.href = 'http://bit.ly/' + 
                    ( location.href.indexOf( '.99' ) > -1 ? 'xxx' : 'yyy' );
```

You're accessing the `document.location` object, instead of the global `location` object.

Comment: I don't see where the OP assigns to `document.location`?

Comment: @Bergi OP's code is `if ( document.location.href ...`; I'm doing `location.href ...` instead.

Comment: Oops, I read "assign" instead of "access". However, `document.location` should work just as `[window.]location`.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I admit, I'm guessing here.